# jQuery CSS Not Changing on mouseenter and mouseleave(I am relatively new to jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the color of heading when a user scrolls over them. However, my code is not working. Yes I am newer to jQuery.

```
$("h1").mouseenter(function(){
("h1").css("color", "#00FF66");
})
$("h1").mouseleave(function(){
("h1").css("color", "#FF00FF");
})
```

I have tried everything in my knowledge. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery's `$(this)` selector to get target the h1 element that is being hovered on

```
$("h1").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "#00FF66");
})
$("h1").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "#FF00FF");
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I wish I could accept the answer sooner.

Answer (score 4):

for that sir, use CSS.

html:

```
<h1>Boo</h1>
```

css:

```
h1{color:#00FF66;}
h1:hover{color:#FF00FF;}
```

hope that helps.

p.s- if you still decide to stick with javascript, i'd suggest Kierchon's answer.

Comment: Useful for people who aren't using the jQuery language and don't know how to.

Comment: + much more native and efficiant